# Cómo obtener el Path de un archivo? Android

Tags: android, xamarin, rutas

La ubicación del archivo en el dispositivo móvil Android es:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Nube_JG/Reportes/Hola/Hola_0.json
```

La línea de código que estoy implementando es:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes + nombreUsuario +_+ReportNumber+.json")
```

Pero no me está funcionando, ¿alguna sugerencia o ayuda de cómo obtener el Path de dicho archivo?

Estoy usando un Android 9.

Comment: Te falta el / después de Reportes y nombreUsuario

Comment: Es un error tipográfico debe ser: System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes/" + nombreUsuario + "/" + nombreUsuario  + "_" + ReportNumber + ".json")

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

prueba esto

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes/" + nombreUsuario + "/" + nombreUsuario  + "_" + ReportNumber + ".json")
```

Comment: Si la pregunta contiene un error tipográfico,solo hay que indicarlo y marcar a cierre, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo, si me sirvió de mucho.

Comment: @Jorgesys una disculpa, soy nuevo en esto, pero gracias, ya me apoyaron.

Comment: Lo siento, solo quería ayudar. Estaré mas pendiente.